# Método para cambiar estatus de tareas

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mvc, poo

Tengo una tabla `tareas` donde están las columnas de `id`, `proyecto_id` y `estatus`, entre otros, pero esos son los que me interesan.

Este proyecto es de alguien más, empezó como programación estructurada y conforme fue creciendo y se agregaron más cosas, se fue modificando a manera que quede como POO, MVC, pero aún le falta mucho por hacer.

Debido a que el código es muy extenso, sólo dejaré una parte de él, esperando se entienda.

**f_tareas.php**

```
<?php
require_once 'f_proyectos.php'; //El modulo de Tareas puede requerir funciones de proyectos.
/**
 * Edita registro de Tarea
 * @param  SafeMySQL $db         [description]
 * @param  int $id         [description]
 * @param  array $data       [description]
 * @param  array  $tareas_mod [description]
 * @return boolean | string [Devuelve TRUE en caso de exito, msg o false en caso de falla]
 */
function editTarea(SafeMySQL $db, $id, $data, $tareas_mod=array()) {
    if ($id > 0) {
        $row = $db->getRow('SELECT f_fin, h_fin, estatus FROM Tareas WHERE id = ?i', $id);
        $f_finA = $row['f_fin'].' '.$row['h_fin'];
        $estatusA = $row['estatus'];
        if (isset($data['solicitud']) && empty($data['solicitud'])) {
            return 'Descripción de solicitud no válida';
        }
        if (isset($data['folio']) && (empty($data['folio']) || $data['folio'] < 1)) {
            $data['folio'] = getFolioTarea($db, 0, 0, $id);
        }
        $checkTime = $f_inicio = $f_fin = false;
        if(isset($data['f_inicio']) && !empty($data['f_inicio']) && $data['estatus'] != 'Cancelada'){
            $f_inicio = $data['f_inicio'].' '.$data['h_inicio'];
            if(validateDate($f_inicio, 'Y-m-d H:i:s'))
                $checkTime = TRUE;
            else return 'Fecha y hora de inicio inválida';
        }
        else unset($data['f_inicio'], $data['h_inicio']);//ignorar en el update
        if(isset($data['f_fin']) && !empty($data['f_fin'])){
            $f_fin = $data['f_fin'].' '.$data['h_fin'];
            if(validateDate($f_fin, 'Y-m-d H:i:s')){
                $f_finA = $f_fin;//se requiere actualizar este dato
                $checkTime = TRUE;
            }
            else{
                unset($data['f_fin'], $data['h_fin']);//ignorar en el update
                if(isset($data['estatus']) && $data['estatus'] == 'Realizada')
                    return 'Asigne fecha y hora final para el estatus establecido.';
            }
        }
        elseif (empty($data['f_fin'])) {
            unset($data['f_fin'], $data['h_fin']);//ignorar en el update
        }
        #Actualiza fecha y hora final si el usuario ha o no concluido tarea
        #siempre y cuando no se haya seleccionado el estatus de Realizada
        if(isset($data['completa']) && $estatusA == 'Pendiente' && $data['estatus'] != 'Realizada'){
            $completa = $data['completa'];
            if($completa == 1 && !validateDate($f_finA, 'Y-m-d H:i:s')){//tarea completada y sin fecha final
                $data['f_fin'] = fechaHora();
                $data['h_fin'] = fechaHora('h');
            }
            elseif ($completa == 0 && validateDate($f_finA, 'Y-m-d H:i:s')) {
                $data['f_fin'] = $data['h_fin'] = '';//se depuran ambos campos
            }
        }
        $sql = "UPDATE Tareas SET ?u WHERE id = $id";
        $result = $db->query($sql, $data);
        if ($result) {
            if(isset($data['detalle']))
                $data['detalle'] = limpia_string($data['detalle']);
            regHistorico($db, 2, 'Tareas', $data, $id); //que:editar
            $proyecto_id = $db->getOne('SELECT proyecto_id FROM Tareas WHERE id = ?i', $id);
            if($proyecto_id > 0){
                #Actualiza modulos relacionados
                $db->query('DELETE IGNORE FROM tareas_mod WHERE tareas_id = ?i', $id);
                if(count($tareas_mod)>0){
                    foreach ($tareas_mod as $modulo_id) {
                        $data2 = array('tareas_id' => $id, 'proyecto_id'=>$proyecto_id, 'modulo_id'=>$modulo_id);
                        $db->query('INSERT INTO tareas_mod SET ?u', $data2);
                    }
                }
            }
            #TIEMPOS DE DESARROLLO
            if($checkTime){
                $nReg = $db->getOne('SELECT 1 FROM tarea_time WHERE tareas_id = ?i', $id);
                //$nReg = $db->numRows($result);
                if(!empty($f_inicio) && $nReg < 1){
                    regTarea_time($id, $f_inicio, $f_fin);//reg periodo de desarrollo
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
}
/**
 * Determina si puede editar TODO bajo las siguientes condiciones:
 * + Puede editar el registro bajo condiciones minimas (editRegTarea)
 * + Su nivel de acceso es < 4
 * @param  integer $idTarea ID Tarea
 * @return boolean  Devuelve TRUE si el usuario tiene permisos avanzados de edicion en el registro
 */
function editAll_RegT($idTarea){
    global $conex;
    if(editRegTarea($idTarea)){
        #Puede editar registro y el usuario tiene permiso de edicion en el modulo
        if($_SESSION['nivelAcc'] < 4){
            #Ademas su nivel es por lo menos departamento
            return TRUE;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
/**
 * Devuelve estatus de la tarea (el valor del indice segun campo ENUM):
 * 1: Registro
 * 2: Pendiente
 * 3: Realizada
 * 4: Cancelada
 * @param  int $idTarea ID Tarea
 * @param  SafeMySQL $conex Conexion BD
 * @return int  Valor del indice
 */
function getEstatus_T($idTarea, SafeMySQL $conex = null){
    if(!isset($conex))
        $conex = new SafeMySQL ();
    return $conex->getOne('SELECT estatus+0 FROM Tareas WHERE id =?i', $idTarea); //+0 :regresar el valor del indice del campo ENUM
}
?>
```

**tarea_model.php**

```
<?php
require_once 'unegocio_model.php';
require_once 'empleado_model.php';
require_once 'proyecto_model.php';
/**
 * Catálogo de Tareas.
 * Las tareas pueden o no estar asociadas a un proyecto.
 */
class Tarea {
    const E_PENDIENTE = 'Pendiente';
    /**
     * Conector a la BD. Objeto de la clase SafeMySQL
     * @var SafeMySQL
     */
    protected $db;
    private $id;
    private $_UNegocio;
    private $_Proyecto;
    private $f_solicitud;
    private $f_inicio;
    private $f_fin;
    private $f_entrega;
    private $solicitud;
    private $detalle;
    private $folio;
    /**
     * Estatus del registro. Puede ser: 'Registro', 'Pendiente', 'Realizada', 'Cancelada'
     * @var string
     */
    private $estatus;
    private $completa;
    private $dias_e;
    private $tiempo;
    private $h_inicio;
    private $h_fin;
    private $prior_id;
    private $orden1;
    private $fh_reg;
    private $id_rh_reg;
    /**
     * Para crear objeto es requerido su ID
     * @param integer    $id ID de Tarea
     * @param SafeMySQL $db [description]
     */
    public function __construct($id, SafeMySQL $db){
        if($db instanceof SafeMySQL){
            $this->db = $db;
        }
        else throw new Exception("Se requiere objeto SafeMySQL");    

        if($id > 0){
            $this->id = $id;
            $this->iniObjeto();
        }
        else throw new Exception("Se requiere ID de Tarea");
    }
    /**
     * Devuelve arreglo de tareas PENDIENTES asociadas al Empleado.
     * @param  SafeMySQL $db    Conex. a BD
     * @param  integer    $idEmp ID del Empleado (opcional)
     * @param  array    $aFiltro Arreglo para aplicar filtros personalizados a la consulta:
     *                           ftroLimit: valore entero como limite para reg a devolver
     *                           proyecto_id: ID de proyecto
     * @return array           [description]
     */
    public static function getTareasPendientes(SafeMySQL $db, $idEmp = 0, $aFiltro=array()){
        $ftroLimit = $proyecto_id = '';
        if(!empty($aFiltro) && is_array($aFiltro)){//condiciones esperadas
            if(isset($aFiltro['ftroLimit']) && $aFiltro['ftroLimit'] > 0){//se envia un valor entero como limite
                $ftroLimit = ' LIMIT '.$aFiltro['ftroLimit'];
            }
            if(isset($aFiltro['proyecto_id'])) $proyecto_id = $aFiltro['proyecto_id'];//se espera ID de proyecto
        }
        $sql = "SELECT t1.id, t1.solicitud, t2.responsable FROM Tareas t1
        INNER JOIN tareas_emp t2 ON t1.id = t2.tareas_id
        LEFT JOIN Proyectos t3 ON t1.proyecto_id = t3.id
        WHERE t1.estatus = 'Pendiente' ";
        if($idEmp > 0){
            $sql.= "AND t2.empleado_id = $idEmp ";
        }
        if($proyecto_id > 0){
            $sql.= "AND t3.id = $proyecto_id ";
        }
        $sql.= $ftroLimit;
        $data = $db->getAll($sql);
        return $data;
    }
    public function getEstatus(){
        return $this->estatus;
    }
    public function getFolio(){
        return $this->folio;
    }
    public function getId(){
        return $this->id;
    }
    /**
     * Devuelve proyecto (si tiene)
     * @return null|Proyecto Proyecto asociado a la tarea o null si no tiene.
     */
    public function getProyecto(){
        return $this->_Proyecto;
    }
    public function getSolicitud(){
        return $this->solicitud;
    }
    /**
     * Inicializa atributos del objeto volviendo a leer el registro
     * @return [type] [description]
     */
    private function iniObjeto(){
        $id = $this->id;
        $db = $this->db;
        $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM Tareas WHERE id = ?i", $id);
        $numRows = $db->numRows($query);
        if ($numRows == 1) {
            $row = $db->fetch($query);
            $this->id = $row["id"];
            $this->_UNegocio = new UNegocio($db, $row['id_uneg']);
            if($row['proyecto_id'] > 0) $this->_Proyecto = new Proyecto($db, $row['proyecto_id']);//opcional en el registro.
            $this->f_solicitud = $row['f_solicitud'];
            $this->f_inicio = $row['f_inicio'];
            $this->f_fin = $row['f_fin'];
            $this->f_entrega = $row['f_entrega'];
            $this->solicitud = $row['solicitud'];
            $this->detalle = $row['detalle'];
            $this->folio = $row['folio'];
            $this->estatus = $row['estatus'];
            $this->completa = $row['completa'];
            $this->dias_e = $row['dias_e'];
            $this->tiempo = $row['tiempo'];
            $this->h_inicio = $row['h_inicio'];
            $this->h_fin = $row['h_fin'];
            $this->prior_id = $row['prior_id'];
            $this->orden1 = $row['orden1'];
            $this->fh_reg = $row['fh_reg'];
            $this->id_rh_reg = $row['id_rh_reg'];
        }
        else {
            throw new Exception("El registro no existe. Id: $id", 0, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

**tareas.php**

```
<?php
/*
 * Modulo de Tareas
 * Parámetros:
 * op1[view-Lista de tareas | new-crear registro| edit-Editar registro]
 * Ejemplos:
 * Nuevo registro: index.php?contenido=tareas&op1=new
 */
require 'includes/sesion.php';
require_once 'models/tarea_model.php';
require_once 'models/soporte_model.php';
require_once 'includes/f_tareas.php';//Libreria Modulo de tareas NOTA: incluye tambien funciones de Proyectos    

if (!isset($conex))
    $conex = new SafeMySQL ();
extract(Perfil::perfilActions('tareas'), EXTR_OVERWRITE); //$tieneAcceso (true|false), $puedeEditar($true|false)
if (!$tieneAcceso) {
    die('Su perfil no tiene acceso a este módulo');
}
$urlNew = '';
if($puedeEditar){
    $urlNew = 'index.php?contenido=tareas&op1=new';
}
$urlLista = 'index.php?contenido=tareas&op1=view';
$opcion1 = 'view'; //lista de tareas
if (filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'op1') !== null) {
    $opcion1 = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'op1', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
}
$opcion2 = ''; //opciones de edicion
if (filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'op2') !== null) {
    $opcion2 = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'op2', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
}    

#Valores para los filtros:
$ftroProy = $_SESSION['ftroProy'];
$ftroEsTarea = $_SESSION['ftroEsTarea'];
$ftroRH1 = $_SESSION['ftroRH1'];
$ftroSearch = $_SESSION['ftroSearch'];
#Otras Variables
//$pCDetalle = array('class' => "jqte-test",'placeholder'=>'Detalle de la tarea', 'rows'=>6, 'max'=>1200);//propiedad predeterminada para detalle de tarea
$pCDetalle = array('class' => "textHtml",'placeholder'=>'Detalle de la tarea', 'rows'=>6, 'max'=>1200);//propiedad predeterminada para detalle de tarea
if ($opcion1 == 'new' && $puedeEditar) { //Nueva Tarea
    //RELACION CON MODULO SOPORTES
    $idSoporte = $_Soporte = null;
    if (filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'idSoporte') !== null) $idSoporte = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'idSoporte', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
    if($idSoporte > 0){
        $aSoportes = Soporte::getRegSoportes($sys_Usuario, array('idSoporte'=>$idSoporte));
        if(empty($aSoportes)){
            showAviso('Falla', 'El registro de soporte con ID ['.$idSoporte.'] no existe o no tiene permiso de acceso.', true);
            exit;
        }
        $_Soporte = new Soporte($conex, $idSoporte);
    }
    //Crear registro...
   //CÓDIGO PARA REGISTRAR UNA NUEVA TAREA Y TAMBIÉN EL VIEW DE ESTE MÓDULO.
} //fin nuevo Tarea
elseif ($opcion1 == 'edit') {//editar registro tarea
    if (null !== filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'id')) {
        $nTarea = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'id');
    }
    if(empty($nTarea))die('Se requiere clave de registro');
    #Obtener registros permitidos para edicion
    $ftroRH1_temp = $ftroRH1;
    if($sys_integranteTarea != 1){
        $ftroRH1_temp = 0;//El usuario no esta limitado a ver solo tarea donde se encuentre como integrante.
    }
    $sqlLista = sqlListaTareas(-1, $ftroRH1_temp,'', '',$nTarea);//
    $row = $conex->getRow($sqlLista);
    $idObtenido = $row['id'];
    if($idObtenido != $nTarea){
        die('El registro no existe o no tiene permitido el acceso.');
    }
    #Fin obtener registros...
    $editAll = editAll_RegT($nTarea);
    $editRegistro = $editSol = $editFEntrega = $editDiasE = $editFInicio = false;
    $esRespTarea = esRespTarea($nTarea, $_SESSION['id']);
    if(editRegTarea($nTarea)){//el estatus y el id de usuario son permitidos
        $editRegistro = true;
    }
    #Consulta del registro
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Tareas WHERE id = $nTarea";
    $result = $conex->query($sql);
    $rows = $conex->fetch($result);
    $proyecto_id = $rows['proyecto_id'];
    $solicitud = $rows['solicitud'];
    $estatus = $rows['estatus'];
    $folio = $rows['folio'];
    $f_entrega = $rows['f_entrega'];
    $f_solicitud = $rows['f_solicitud'];
    $prior_id=$rows['prior_id'];
    $f_inicio = $rows['f_inicio'];
    $h_inicio = $rows['h_inicio'];
    $f_fin = $rows['f_fin'];
    $h_fin = $rows['h_fin'];
    $detalle = $rows['detalle'];
    $completa = $rows['completa'];
    $dias_e = $rows['dias_e'];
    $fh_reg = $rows['fh_reg'];
    $id_rh_reg = $rows['id_rh_reg'];    

    $userRegistro = $conex->getOne('SELECT usuario FROM Usuarios WHERE id = ?i', $id_rh_reg);
    $sProyecto = $proyModulo = $tareas_mod = '';
    if ($proyecto_id > 0) {
        $sql = "SELECT proyecto FROM Proyectos WHERE id = $proyecto_id";
        $sProyecto = $conex->getOne($sql);
        #arreglo con modulos en el proyecto
        $proyModulo = $conex->getIndCol('id', 'SELECT id, modulo FROM proy_mod WHERE proyecto_id = ?i ORDER BY modulo', $proyecto_id);
        $tareas_mod = $conex->getCol('SELECT modulo_id FROM tareas_mod WHERE tareas_id = ?i', $nTarea);
    }
    #revisar estatus
    if($estatus == 'Realizada'){
        if(empty($f_fin) || dateDifference($f_inicio, $f_fin, '%R') == '-'){
            #CORRECCION AUTOMATICA
            $estatus  = 'Pendiente';
            $conex->query("UPDATE Tareas SET estatus = '$estatus' WHERE id = ?i",$nTarea);
        }
    }
    #PERMISOS EN EL FORMULARIO
    $propC1 = $pC3 = $pC4 = $pC5 = $pCModulos = 1;//prop. disabled
    $propC2 = 2;//readonly en inputText
    $elpost = $btnEnviar = '';
    if($editRegistro){
        $editSol = pEditSolicitud($esRespTarea, $estatus, $editAll);
        $editFEntrega = pEditFEntrega($esRespTarea, $f_entrega, $dias_e, $editAll);
        $editDiasE = pEditDiasE($nTarea, $editRegistro, $editAll);
        $editFInicio = pEditFInicio($esRespTarea, $f_inicio, $editAll);
        $pCModulos = array('multiple'=>'', 'id'=>'tareas_mod');
        $elpost = 'index.php?contenido=tareas&op1=' . $opcion1 . '&op2=save&id=' . $nTarea;
        $btnEnviar = TRUE;
        if($editAll){
            $propC1 = '';
        }
        if($editSol){
            $propC2 ='';
        }
        if($editFEntrega) {
            $pC3 = '';
        }
        if($editFInicio) $pC4 = '';
        if($editDiasE) $pC5 = '';
    }    

    $indicaTareaTerm = indicaTareaTerm($nTarea, $proyecto_id);
    #Realizar cambios luego del post
    if (filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'op3')!== null && $editRegistro) {//ACTUALIZAR REGISTRO
        /*
        + El responsable puede editar si no existe una fecha valida aun.
        + Solo quien tenga permiso de editar todo el registro puede cambiar fecha de entrega o inicio.
        */
        $lEdita = $lRecarga = TRUE;
        $detalle2 = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'detalle');
        $solicitud2 = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'solicitud');
        $estatus2 = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'estatus');
        $prior_id2 = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'prior_id');
        $f_entrega2 = $f_entrega;
        if($editFEntrega)
            $f_entrega2 = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'f_entrega');
        $dias_e2 = (int)filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'dias_e', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
        $f_inicio2 = $f_inicio;
        if($editFInicio) {
            $f_inicio2 = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'f_inicio');
            $h_inicio2 = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'h_inicio');
        }
        $f_fin2 = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'f_fin');
        $h_fin2 = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'h_fin');
        $tareas_mod = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'tareas_mod', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY);//arreglo de opciones seleccionadas
        if($estatus2 == 'Realizada'){
            if(!validateDate($f_fin2.' '.$h_fin2, 'Y-m-d H:i:s')){
                //list($f_fin2, $h_fin2) = explode(' ', fechaHora('fh'));
                //No es necesario omitir guardar...
                jsAlert('Para concluir la tarea debe asignar fecha y hora final');
                $lRecarga = FALSE;
            }
            if(dateDifference($f_inicio2, $f_fin2, '%R') == '-'){
                $lEdita = FALSE;
                jsAlert('Las fechas no son válidas, no se permite cambio de estatus');
            }
        }
        #COMIENZA REGISTRO A GUARDAR...
        $registro = array(); $lTareaTerm = FALSE;
        if($indicaTareaTerm){
            $completa2 = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'completa');
            if(empty($completa2)) $completa2 = 0;
            $registro['completa'] = $completa2;
            if($completa != $completa2){
                $msg1 = 'La tarea NO ha sido completada.';
                if($completa2 == 1) {
                    $msg1 = 'La tarea ha sido completada.';
                }
                $lTareaTerm = TRUE;
            }
        }
        if($editAll){//permisos avanzados de edicion ()
            $registro['estatus'] = $estatus2;
            $registro['f_fin'] = $f_fin2;
            $registro['h_fin'] = $h_fin2;
            $registro['prior_id'] = $prior_id2;
        }
        if($editDiasE){
            $registro['dias_e'] = $dias_e2;
            if($dias_e2 > 0 && validateDate($f_inicio2) && (!validateDate($f_entrega2) || $f_entrega2 < $f_inicio2)){
                #Hay dias asignados y se ha establecido fecha de inicio y la fecha estimada de entrega
                #aun no esta definida o es incorrecta.
                $f_entrega2 = sumaDiasH($f_inicio2, $dias_e2);
            }
        }
        if($editFEntrega && !empty($f_entrega2)) {
            $registro['f_entrega'] = $f_entrega2;//
            if(validateDate($f_entrega2) && validateDate($f_inicio2)){//
                #Hay asignada fecha de inicio y fecha estimada de entrega.
                #Los dias estimados siempre se recalculan en base a estas dos fechas.
                $registro['dias_e'] = dateDifference($f_inicio2, $f_entrega2);
            }
        }
        if($editFInicio) {
            $registro['f_inicio'] = $f_inicio2;//
            $registro['h_inicio'] = $h_inicio2;//
        }
        if($editSol){//es el responsable y el estatus es Registro
            $registro['solicitud'] = $solicitud2;
        }
        $registro['detalle'] = $detalle2;
        if($lEdita){
            $result = editTarea($conex, $nTarea, $registro, $tareas_mod);
            if ($result === true) {
                if($lTareaTerm){
                    regHistorico($conex, 4, 'Tareas', $msg1, $nTarea);//se actualiza estatus
                }
                #Actualiza tiempo de desarrollo
                concluyeT_time($nTarea, $conex);
                if($lRecarga){
                    echo 'Registro actualizado.';
                    ?>
                    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2; url=<?php echo $urlLista; ?>"/>
                    <?php
                    exit;
                }
            }
            else {
                echo 'Falla al guardar. ' . $result;
            }
        }
    }//fin if(isset($_POST['op3']))
    #FORMULARIO DE EDICION
    $idRespTarea = $conex->getOne('SELECT empleado_id FROM tareas_emp WHERE tareas_id = ?i AND responsable = 1', $nTarea);    

    ////Mostrar formulario Editar Tarea
    $propForm = array('file'=>true);
    $aTabs = array(1=>'General',2=>'Integrantes');
    if($_SESSION['tarea_p3'] > 0){
        $aTabs[3] = 'Adjuntos';//pos. 5
    }
    $aTabs[4] = 'Historial';
    if($_SESSION['tarea_p2'] > 0){
        $aTabs[5] = 'T. Desarrollo';//pos. 5
    }
    $aPrior=$conex->getIndCol('id', "SELECT id, descripcion FROM Prioridad");
    $aPrior[0] = 'Sin especificar';
    $idTab = 'eTarea';
    $opsIniMod = array('uN'=>$urlNew, 'urlBack'=>$urlLista);
    iniModulo('Tareas - Edición ['.$folio.']', '', $opsIniMod);
    abreFormTab($idTab, $aTabs, $elpost, '', $propForm);
    abreTab($idTab, 1);
    abreBloque('Datos generales');
    inputText('<', 'Folio', 'folio', $folio, '', '', '', 2);
    inputText('>', 'Fecha de solicitud', 'f_solicitud', $f_solicitud, '', '', '', 1);
    inputText('<', 'Solicitud', 'solicitud', $solicitud, $solicitud, array('required' => 'si'), '',$propC2);
    inputText('>', 'Proyecto', 'sProyecto', $sProyecto, '', '', '', 1);
    inputText('<', 'Días estimados', 'dias_e', $dias_e, 'Días hábiles estimados', '', 'number', $pC5);
    inputText('>', 'Fecha Estimada Entrega', 'f_entrega', $f_entrega, '', array('class' => 'ctrlFecha'), '', $pC3);
    inputText('<', 'Fecha Inicio', 'f_inicio', $f_inicio, '', array('class' => 'ctrlFecha'), '', $pC4);
    inputText('>', 'Hora', 'h_inicio', $h_inicio, '', array('class' => 'ctrlHora'), '', $pC4);
    inputText('<', 'Fecha Fin', 'f_fin', $f_fin, '', array('class' => 'ctrlFecha'), '', $propC1);
    inputText('>', 'Hora', 'h_fin', $h_fin, '', array('class' => 'ctrlHora'), '', $propC1);
    showSelect('<', 'Estatus', 'estatus', $estatus, $estatusTarea, 'Estatus de la Tarea', $propC1);
    showSelect('>', 'Prioridad', 'prior_id', $prior_id, $aPrior, 'Seleccionar prioridad de la tarea',$propC1);
    if($indicaTareaTerm){
        inputCheck('*', 'completa', 'Tarea completada', $completa, 'Seleccionar para indicar tarea terminada');
    }
    $result = $conex->query('SELECT t1.cuando, t1.detalle, t2.usuario
        FROM historial t1 LEFT JOIN Usuarios t2 ON t1.idEmpleado = t2.id
        WHERE t1.tabla = "Tareas" AND t1.clave1 = ?i AND t1.que = 4 ORDER BY t1.cuando DESC LIMIT 1', $nTarea);
    $nReg = $conex->numRows($result);
    if($nReg > 0){
        $row = $conex->fetch($result);
        label1('*','* Nota', $row['detalle'].'::'.$row['cuando'].'::'.$row['usuario']);
    }
    textArea('*', 'detalle', 'Detalle', $detalle, '', $pCDetalle);
    inputText('-', '', 'op3', 1, '', '', 'hidden');
    cierraBloque();
    abreBloque('Otros datos');
    showSelect('<', 'Módulos implicados', 'tareas_mod[]', $tareas_mod, $proyModulo, 'Módulos del proyecto', $pCModulos);
    imageButton('>', 15,'Enviar correo', array('onclick'=>"ventanaE('divCorreo', 'correo.php?id=$nTarea');"));
    label1('<', 'Registró', $userRegistro);
    label1('>', 'el', $fh_reg);
    cierraBloque();
    cierraTab();    

    abreTab($idTab, 2);
    abreBloque('Personal involucrado');
    abreDiv('divEmpT');
    $id = $nTarea;
    require 'equipoTarea.php';
    cierraDiv();
    cierraBloque();
    cierraTab();    

    if($_SESSION['tarea_p3'] > 0){
        abreTab($idTab, 3);
        abreBloque('Lista de archivos adjuntos');
        abreDiv('divAdjT');
        //$id = $nTarea;
        require 'tareas_adj.php';
        cierraDiv();
        cierraBloque();
        cierraTab();
    }    

    abreTab($idTab, 4);
    abreBloque('Historial de cambios y registros en bitácora');
    abreDiv('divHisT');
    require 'tareas_hist.php';
    cierraDiv();
    cierraBloque();
    cierraTab();    

    if($_SESSION['tarea_p2'] > 0){
        abreTab($idTab, 5);
        abreBloque('Tiempo de trabajo registrado.');
        abreDiv('divTaTime');
        require 'tarea_time.php';
        cierraDiv();
        cierraBloque();
        cierraTab();
    }
    cierraFormTab($btnEnviar, $urlLista);
    abreDiv('divCorreo');
    cierraDiv();
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
} //fin editar tarea
```

Lo que necesito es:

Crear un método `cancelTareasPendientes` en **tarea_model.php** que al momento de seleccionar un **proyecto**, al dar 'Aceptar', cambie el `estatus` de ese proyecto de `Pendiente` a `Cancelada`.

El proyecto se seleccionará en **tareas.php** por medio de un `select box`.

Como el proyecto ha pasado por muchas manos, me cuesta trabajo entender todas las funciones, de antemano gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Todavía está un poco borrosa tu necesidad, en concreto la respuesta inmediata sería **ok, hazlo** pero me imagino que necesitas ayuda para revisar y/o entender el código que posteas. Lamentablemente es más complejo de lo que se puede entender en estos archivos, mi recomendación es, crea un método simple y consúmelo:

```
public function cancelTareasPendientes(){
    return $db->query("UPDATE Tareas SET estatus = 'cancelado' WHERE id = ". $this->id);
}
```

No sabemos como se crea el objeto `Tarea` ni qué parámetros le pasan a éste, tampoco sabemos si el estatus y el id son numéricos o texto,
de donde se consume esta clase y que se espera de regreso, a que script se realiza la petición de actualización, que hace la clase SafeMySQL y qué metodos tiene... esto podría seguir.

Me parece que aún necesitas estudiar tu problema un poco para poder proporcionar una pregunta más detallada pero espero que esto te ayude a encontrar el camino pronto.

Comment: No puedo poner todo el código por el límite de caracteres, y basicamente eso es lo que quiero hacer, el `UPDATE` , pero no sé de qué manera vincular el método con el "controlador" que sería **tareas.php**, para que al seleccionar un proyecto y dar Aceptar, cambie los `estatus`, el SafeMysql tiene funciones como getRow, getCol, getAll.

Comment: Entiendo, igual poner todo el código sería descomunal. Me parece que tienes que empezar viendo a qué script se va a hacer el request al dar click en `Aceptar`, de igual forma que parámetros se enviarían y seguir el hilo de clases y funciones que estarías usando. Una vez que sepas como inicializar un objeto `Tarea` solamente tendrías que llamar al método así `(new Tarea($parametros_necesarios))->cancelTareasPendientes();` que ejecutaría el sql con los parámetros que has pasado en la inicialización para `$this->db` y `$this->id`

Comment: De momento esto es lo que tengo en mi **tarea_model.php**

`public static function cancelTareasP(SafeMySQL $db, $proyecto_id){
    return $db->query("UPDATE Tareas SET estatus = 'Cancelada' WHERE proyecto_id = '$proyecto_id'");      
}`

Comment: Y en mi **tareas.php**

    `elseif ($opcion1 == 'opcav' && $puedeEditar){
        $elpost = $btnEnviar = '';
        $elpost = 'index.php?contenido=tareas&op1=view';
        $btnEnviar = TRUE;
        $propForm = array('file'=>true);
        $propS = array('onchange' => "actSelEmp('empleado_id', $idTipoU, 'proyecto_id')");
        $aTabs = array(1=>'Cancelar pendientes');
        $idTab = 'opcAv';
        $opsIniMod = array('urlBack'=>$urlLista);
        iniModulo('Opciones avanzadas', '', $opsIniMod);`

Comment: `abreFormTab($idTab, $aTabs, $elpost, '', $propForm);
        abreTab($idTab, 1);
        abreBloque('Cancelación de tareas pendientes');
        $strProyecto = $conex->getIndCol('id', sqlProyectos());//proyectos validos.
        showSelect('<', 'Proyecto', 'proyecto_id', -1, $strProyecto, 'Seleccionar proyecto', $propS);
        cierraBloque();
        cierraTab();
        cierraFormTab($btnEnviar, $urlLista);
        Tarea::cancelTareasP($conex, $proyecto_id);
    }`

`$strProyecto` te muestra el `nombre` de los proyectos que puedes elejir, lo que necesito es el `id`.

Comment: Me parece que la respuesta está en `$strProyecto = $conex->getIndCol('id', sqlProyectos());` probablemente `sqlProyectos()` tenga el Id del proyecto o a ese nivel una función similar.  Por ahora se ve bien el camino que estás tomando

Comment: @PalomaAG ¿tienes el código del botón, es decir el form que encierra el botón?

Comment: `// Cierra Formulario creado con abreFormTab
 * @param  string  $btnEnviar [description]
function cierraFormTab($btnEnviar = '', $urlReturn = '', $btnReset = false, $btnElim = '') {
    echo '<div class="buttonsFoot">';
    if ($urlReturn != '') {
        echo "<input type=\"button\" name=\"btnF1\" class=\"button\" value=\"Regresar\" onclick=\"GotoURL('$urlReturn');\" />";
    }
    if ($btnReset) {
        echo '<input type="reset" name="btnF3" value="Restablecer" />';
    }`

Comment: `#Btn para guardar
    if (!empty($btnEnviar)) {
        if(is_bool($btnEnviar))
            $btnEnviar = 'Aceptar';
        echo '<input type="submit" name="btnF2" class="enviar" value="'.$btnEnviar.'" />';
    }
    if (!empty($btnElim)) {
        echo "<input type='button' name='btnF4' class='button' value='Eliminar'  onclick='elimReg(\"$btnElim\");' />";
    }
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</form></div>';
}`